# Fixed position full height div scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

I am trying to achieve an effect where I have a full height hero area that is fixed position, and moves down as you scroll. Then once off screen, I would like the content beneath it to move in the normal scroll flow. I have gotten this to work somewhat using JS. However, I can't scroll at all unless I set a fixed height to the containing div. I have included a codepen with the result so far, but obviously would like to get rid of the explicit fixed height.

```
.container {
  min-height: 6000px;
}

#overlay {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#content {
  background: blue;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/kylehagler/pen/MPzzKv

Comment: I think you're trying to achieve something like parallax effect, right? You may want to check out this pen if you are really into parallax. 
He used pure css ;) https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw

Comment: not exactly, i am trying to achieve like this site https://unterfreiemhimmel.net/en/

Answer (score 0):

Because you used the position `fixed` to all the elements inside the `container`. Inside the DOM, there is actually no element inside this `container`, so you forced to set a `min-height`

Now if I set the content to position `static`, which is default position value. It should works as you expected.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('#overlay').css('top', $(this).scrollTop());

  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $(window).height()) {
    var distance = $(this).scrollTop() - $(window).height();

    $('#content').css('top', -distance);
  } else {
    $('#content').css('top', '0');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
}

#overlay {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#content {
  background: blue;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div id="overlay"></div>

  <div id="content">
    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>

    <p>Ut tortor tellus, lacinia a est vitae, aliquet egestas lorem. Suspendisse scelerisque ligula quis auctor lobortis. Vivamus in convallis lectus. Ut euismod a nisi pulvinar molestie. Integer sagittis, mauris in semper suscipit, leo mauris condimentum
      elit, eu dapibus velit massa placerat felis. Nulla fringilla lacus non ipsum suscipit viverra. Suspendisse vitae metus nec enim sagittis porta.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: yes but in this case the blue div starts to immediately scroll. the reason to keep it fixed is so I can wait until the red div fully exits the screen before the content div starts moving